# Finding sets such that the cartesian product gives the natural numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

I just noticed that for these two sequences:
$$
A={1,2,4,8,16,32\dots2^n\dots}\\
B={1,3,5,7,9,11\dots2n+1\dots}
$$
The following holds:
$$
\forall x \in \mathbb{N}, x=a_i·b_j \text{ for unique values of i and j}\\ 
a_{n+1}-a_{n}\geq a_n-a_{n-1}\\
b_{n+1}-b_{n}\geq b_n-b_{n-1}\\
$$

Are there any other increasing sequences of integers A and B that satisfy this?

**Edit:**

I'm looking for sequences in which the first condition holds for a unique value of $i$ and $j$, but, even if we leave that aside, I can't find any sequence that doesn't contain the original $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Do you want each number to arise _uniquely_ as the product of an $a$ and a $b$?

Comment: Yes, that is VERY important. Otherwise you could take almost any pair of sequences

Comment: This means that every prime has to be in exactly one of the sequences, and each sequence consists of all the products of powers of the primes in it. That severely restricts which kind of sequences we can have.

Comment: The problem is, if you start putting the problems in terms of number theory, it's difficult to prove that the constraints 2 & 3 hold. For example, if you take the series $A={1,2,4,5,8,10,11,16,17,20,22,23,25,31...}$ and $B={1,3,7,9,13,17,21,27,29,37,39...}$, for which the first condition works, the other two are just ignored.

Comment: That is ***NOT*** Cartesian product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two sequences which you have found are the only sequences which satisfy all three of your constraints.

First we notice that since we must be able to write $1=a_i b_j$ for some $i$ and $j$, that $1$ must be an element of both sequences. Thus $a_1=b_1=1$. (Otherwise $1$ would not appear in one of the sequences since the sequences are increasing)

Then the following is true:

Each natural number $n>1$ can be in at most one of the sequences.

This is because if $a_i=b_j=n$, then we would have $a_1b_j = a_i b_1 = n$, contradicting the uniqueness requirement for writing $n$ as a product of elements from each sequence.

We will also make repeated use of the fact that if $n$ is a natural number such that all of the proper factors of $n$ other than possibly $n$ itself appear in one of the sequences (i.e. either all in $A$ or all in $B$) then $n$ must appear in one of the sequences.

To prove this, suppose without loss of generality that all of the proper factors of $n$ are in $A$. We must be able to write $n=a_ib_j$ for some $i$ and $j$. Suppose that both $a_i\neq n$ and $b_j \neq n$. Then $b_j$ is a proper factor of $n$ that is not equal to $1$ or $n$ and so $b_j$ appears in $A$. But then $b_j$ appears in both sequences, which is a contradiction.

We note that since $2=a_i b_j$ for some $i$ and $j$, that $2$ must appear in one of the sequences, and since each sequence is strictly increasing, either $a_2=2$ or $b_2 = 2$. Without loss of generality, suppose that $a_2=2$.

Since we have that $3=a_i b_j$ for some $i$ and $j$, we see that $3$ must also be in one of the sequences. (Indeed, any prime number must be in one of the sequences) Since the sequences are increasing, either $a_3=3$ or $b_2=3$.

Suppose that $a_3=3$. Then I claim that $a_n=n$ for all $n$. I will prove this by induction.
The base cases are true since $a_n=n$ for $n=1,2,3$. Suppose that $a_k=k$ for all $k \leq n$ where $n \geq 3$. We will show that $a_{n+1}=n+1$.

Suppose that $a_{n+1} \neq n+1$. (And hence that $n+1$ does not appear in $a$) For any $k\leq n$ we see that $k$ is not in the second sequence since each natural number can appear in at most one of the sequences. Thus all of the factors of $n+1$ occur only in the first sequence. We see that in order for us to write $n+1$ as a product of elements from each sequence, that $n+1$ itself must be in one of the sequences, and so $b_2=n+1$. The constraints then require that $b_3 \geq 2b_2-b_1 = 2n+1$, and so $n+2$ does not appear in the second sequence. Since $n+1$ is not a factor of $n+2$, we see that $n+2$ must be in the first sequence, and so $a_{n+1}=n+2$. Again, since $n+1$ is not a factor of $n+3$, we see that $n+3$ must be in one of the sequences. But $a_{n+2}\geq 2a_{n+1}-a_n=n+4$ and $b_3 \geq 2n+1 > n+3$ since $n\geq 3$, and so $n+3$ can not be in either sequence, a contradiction.

Thus $a_{n+1}=n+1$, and so $a_n=n$ for all $n$ by induction. But this is clearly also a contradiction since then the second sequence can only contain the number $1$!.

Thus we must have that $b_2=3$. We can then also see that $a_3=4$ since $4$ must appear in one of the sequences (indeed, any square of a prime number must appear in one of the sequences), and $b_3 \geq 5$.

We will now prove the following claim by induction:

For some natural number $n$, if $k \leq 2^n$ then $k$ appears in $A$ iff $k$ is a power of $2$, $k$ appears in $B$ iff $k$ is odd, and $k$ appears in neither sequence otherwise.

We see that this would imply that the sequences must coincide with the two which you have already found.

Our claim is true for $n=1$ and $n=2$ as we showed above. Suppose that it is true for some $n$.

We first note that any even numbers between $2^n$ and $2^{n+1}$ can already be written as a product of elements from each list, since any such number is of the           form $m2^k$ where $k\leq n$ and $m$ is an odd number less than $2^n$. Thus these even numbers do not appear in either sequence.

Now note that that the inductive hypothesis implies that $a_{n}=2^{n-1}$ and $a_{n+1}=2^n$, and so $a_{n+2}\geq 2a_{n+1}-a_n = 2^n + 2^{n-1}$.

Suppose that $m$ is an odd number such that $0<m<2^{n-1}$. I claim that $2^n+m$ lies in $B$. Any proper factor of $2^n+m$ must be odd, and at most $\frac{2^n+m}{2}<2^n$, and hence appears in $B$ by the inductive hypothesis. Thus $2^n+m$ must lie in one of the sequences. But $a_{n+1}<2^n+m<a_{n+2}$, and so $2^n+m$ must appear in $B$.

Now we will show that if $m$ is an odd number with $2^{n-1}<m<2^n$ that $2^n+m$ also appears in the second sequence. We proceed inductively. Suppose that all of the odd numbers less than $2^n+m$ have already been shown to lie in $B$. Then all of the proper factors of $2^n+m$ are odd and hence lie in $B$, and so $2^n+m$ appears in one of the sequences. Suppose that it is the first one. i.e. that $a_{n+2}=2^n+m$ We see then that $a_{n+3}\geq 2^n+2m \geq 2^{n}+2(2^{n-1}+1)=2^{n+1}+2$ and so $2^{n+1}$ does not appear in the first sequence. But all of its proper factors appear in the first sequence, and so $B$ contains $2^{n+1}$. But now consider the odd number $s=2^{n+1}+1$. All of its proper factors are at most $\frac{s}{2}<2^n+1$ and so lie in $B$. Thus $s$ appears in one of the sequences, and can not appear in $A$. Thus $s$ appears in $B$, and so $2^{n+1}$ and $2^{n+1}+1$ are consecutive terms in $B$. But their difference is $1<b_2-b_1$, which is a contradiction.

Thus $2^n+m$ must be in the second list, and so we see that all odd numbers less than $2^{n+1}$ are in the second list. Finally, $2^{n+1}$ has all of its factors in the first sequence, and so must appear in one of the sequences. It can not appear in the second sequence, since the element following $2^{n+1}-1$ must be at least $2^{n+1}+1$, and so $2^{n+1}$ appears in the first sequence, and so the results is true for $n+1$ as well.

This proves our claim.

Comment: Wow. I thought there really were some other solutions, but a proof is a proof. Thank you very much.